# How to pass multi value of checkbox list to stored procedure in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have developed a page like as below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <td align="right">  Collection Area</td>
            <td>   :</td>
            <td align="left">  
             <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkCollAreaNewFile" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Retail Banking Division">Retail Banking Division</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Chittagong Zone">Chittagong Zone</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Khulna">Khulna</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Sylhet">Sylhet</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Rajshahi">Rajshahi</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Barisal">Barisal</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>


            </td>
            <td align="right"> Disbursed Area</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" style="margin-left: 40px">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkDisbAreaNewFile" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="DSDisbAreaNewFile" DataTextField="RegionName" 
                    DataValueField="RegionName">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSDisbAreaNewFile" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [RegionName] FROM [DDRegion]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
            <td> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="right">  &nbsp;  Loan Type</td>
            <td>   &nbsp;:</td>
            <td align="left">  
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLLoanTypeNewFile" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                    DataSourceID="DSAssignCELoanType" DataTextField="LType" DataValueField="LType">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="%">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSAssignCELoanType" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [LType] FROM [DDLoanType] ORDER BY [LType]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource> 
            </td>
            <td align="right"> Cycle</td>
            <td>  :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCycleNewFile" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="X">X</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="right">  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>   &nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">  
                <asp:Label ID="lblMsBx" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="right"> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" style="margin-left: 40px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnRankUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
                    onclick="btnRankUpdate_Click"/>
            </td>
            <td> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td align="right">  &nbsp;</td>
            <td>   &nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">  
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp;</td>
            <td>  &nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" style="margin-left: 40px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

When I press button my stored procedure will be run and update the
record. my stored procedure as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[WebRecNewFileAssign] 
@ParmAppLoanType varchar(100),
@ParmBRegion varchar(1000), --Disbursed Area
@ParmUserBrDiv varchar(1000), -- Collection Area
@AssingCycle varchar(100)
as
begin
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  dbo.TblDisburseInfo.DisbID FROM dbo.TblDisburseInfo INNER JOIN
    dbo.TblMasterInfo ON dbo.TblDisburseInfo.DisbAppID = dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID
    WHERE (dbo.TblDisburseInfo.DisbRecAssignTo IS NULL) AND (dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanType = @ParmAppLoanType) AND 
    (dbo.TblDisburseInfo.DisbBr in(SELECT BrName FROM DDBranchName Where BRegion in(@ParmBRegion) ))
    ORDER BY dbo.TblDisburseInfo.DisbAmt DESC

  declare @tdisbid as int
  declare @cnt as int
  set @cnt = 1
  declare @maxcnt as int

  select @maxcnt = MAX(reid) from [dbo].[TblRecAssignName] WHERE ReAssignName in (SELECT LogId FROM TblUserTest 
        where UserBrDiv in(@ParmUserBrDiv) AND ReCycle=@AssingCycle)

  OPEN db_cursor   
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tdisbid   

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
          BEGIN   
               update [OptimaUCBL].[dbo].[TblDisburseInfo]
               set DisbRecAssignTo = (select ReAssignName from [OptimaUCBL].[dbo].[TblRecAssignName] 
                    where [ReID] = @cnt AND ReAssignName in (SELECT LogId FROM TblUserTest 
                    where UserBrDiv in (@ParmUserBrDiv) AND ReCycle=@AssingCycle))
               where [DisbID] = @tdisbid

               if @cnt = @maxcnt 
                  set @cnt = 1
               else 
                  set @cnt = @cnt + 1                      

               FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tdisbid   
          END   

      CLOSE db_cursor   
      DEALLOCATE db_cursor

end
```

Finally my code (C#)::

```
 protected void btnRankUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myDisbArea = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ChkDisbAreaNewFile.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ChkDisbAreaNewFile.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                myDisbArea = myDisbArea + "'" + ChkDisbAreaNewFile.Items[i].Value + "' ,";
            }
        }
        string NewDisbAreaNewFile = myDisbArea.Substring(myDisbArea.Length - (myDisbArea.Length), (myDisbArea.Length - 1));           
        string AreaSelected = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ChkCollAreaNewFile.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ChkCollAreaNewFile.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                AreaSelected = AreaSelected + "'" + ChkCollAreaNewFile.Items[i].Value + "' ,";
            }
        }
        string NewAreaSelected = AreaSelected.Substring(AreaSelected.Length - (AreaSelected.Length), (AreaSelected.Length - 1));


            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "WebRecNewFileAssign";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParmAppLoanType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DDLLoanTypeNewFile.SelectedValue;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParmBRegion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(NewDisbAreaNewFile);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParmUserBrDiv", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(NewAreaSelected);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssingCycle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DDLCycleNewFile.SelectedValue;
            com.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lblMsBx.Text = "Record updated successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
    }
```

When I pressed update button `Record updated successfully` message show but record is not updated. Where is my problem, I can't identify. Pls support me any one.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to manually put values in your update query(written in store procedure) and checked how many rows are updated ?   because your Message is just get confirmation of query run successfully not about how many rows updated...so first check your update query  manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `IN` clause `where UserBrDiv in(@ParmUserBrDiv)` isn't going to work like that so no records are actually selected. You use this in two different places, getting the `@maxcnt`, which will always be zero because of it, and then trying to update the actual table, which will never select any rows because of it. What you need to do is build this UDF in your database:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.CSVToTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.CSVToTable

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable]
(
    @KeyValue VARCHAR(8000),
    @StringInput VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE
(
    [KeyValue] VARCHAR(8000),
    [String] VARCHAR(8000)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput, 
            ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
            LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
            ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 0),
            LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [KeyValue], [String] )
        VALUES ( @KeyValue, @String )
    END

    RETURN
END

GO
```

then put this statement just above the first query you need to fix up:

```
SELECT String
INTO #brdiv
FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@ParmUserBrDiv)
```

and then change your queries to be this:

```
SELECT @maxcnt = MAX(reid)
FROM [dbo].[TblRecAssignName]
WHERE ReAssignName in (
    SELECT LogId
    FROM TblUserTest
    WHERE UserBrDiv IN (
        SELECT String
        FROM #brdiv
    ) AND ReCycle=@AssingCycle)

UPDATE [OptimaUCBL].[dbo].[TblDisburseInfo]
SET DisbRecAssignTo = (
    SELECT ReAssignName
    FROM [OptimaUCBL].[dbo].[TblRecAssignName]
    WHERE [ReID] = @cnt AND
        ReAssignName in (
            SELECT LogId
            FROM TblUserTest
            WHERE UserBrDiv IN (
                SELECT String
                FROM #brdiv
            ) AND ReCycle=@AssingCycle
        )
)
WHERE [DisbID] = @tdisbid
```

Finally, remove the single quotes from the comma-delimited string and just delimit the values like this:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Just change the Store Procedure like bellow:

```
Declare @AppName varchar(100) ='Rahman',
-- @AppID int ='%',
 @AppLoanType  varchar(100)='Auto Loan',
 @AppSourceBrName varchar(100)='%',
 @AppSourceCode varchar(100)='%',
 @AppLoanStatus varchar(100)='%',
 @AppAsignTo varchar(100)='%',
 @DisbAcSb varchar(100)='%',
 @DisbAcLoan varchar(100)='%',
 --@DisbDate varchar(100)='01Jan1990',
 --@DisbDate2 varchar(100)='01Dec2013',
 --@DisbExpDate varchar(100)='01Jan1990',
 --@DisbExpDate2 varchar(100)='01Dec2013',
 -- @DisbEMIDate varchar(100)='01Jan1990',
 --@DisbEMIDate2 varchar(100)='01Dec2013',
 @DisbNoofOD int='%',
 @DisbRecAssignTo varchar(100)='%'

SELECT     MI.AppID, MI.AppTitle, MI.AppName, MI.AppjointTitle, MI.AppJointAppName, 
               (CASE WHEN MI.AppJointAppName LIKE '' OR  MI.AppJointAppName IS NULL THEN MI.AppTitle + ' ' + MI.AppName ELSE MI.AppTitle + ' ' + MI.AppName + ' & ' + MI.AppjointTitle
               + ' ' + MI.AppJointAppName END) AS ClientNAME, MI.AppSourceBrName, MI.AppSourceCode, MI.AppReqeustAmt, MI.AppLoanType, 
              MI.AppLoanStatus, MI.AppAsignTo, DI.DisbAcSb, DI.DisbAcLoan, DI.DisbAmt, DI.DisbDate, DI.DisbExpDate, 
              DI.DisbEMIDate, DI.DisbNoofOD, DI.DisbRecAssignTo 
      FROM dbo.TblMasterInfo MI LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblDisburseInfo  DI ON MI.AppID = DI.DisbAppID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblPrePostApproval PPA ON MI.AppID = PPA.Appid                      
      WHERE  (AppName like '%' + @AppName OR AppName like @AppName + '%' OR AppName like '%' + @AppName + '%')
      --AND (MI.AppID =@AppID)
      AND (MI.AppLoanType like @AppLoanType) 
      AND (MI.AppSourceBrName LIKE @AppSourceBrName) 
      AND (MI.AppSourceCode LIKE @AppSourceCode)
      AND (MI.AppLoanStatus like @AppLoanStatus) 
      AND (MI.AppAsignTo like @AppAsignTo) 
      AND (DI.DisbAcSb LIKE @DisbAcSb) 
      --AND (DI.DisbAcLoan LIKE @DisbAcLoan) 
      --AND (DATEADD(s,1,DI.DisbDate) &gt; @DisbDate)  
      --AND (DATEADD(s,-1,DI.DisbDate) &lt; @DisbDate2) 
      --AND (DATEADD(s,1,DI.DisbExpDate) &gt; @DisbExpDate)  
      --AND (DATEADD(s,-1,DI.DisbExpDate) &lt; @DisbExpDate2) 
      --AND (DATEADD(s,1,DI.DisbEMIDate) &gt; @DisbEMIDate)  
      --AND (DATEADD(s,-1,DI.DisbEMIDate) &lt; @DisbEMIDate2) 
      AND (DI.DisbNoofOD = @DisbNoofOD) 
      AND (DI.DisbRecAssignTo LIKE @DisbRecAssignTo)
```